# Joining nested lists and adding column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list containing two matrices:

```
a <- list("m1"=matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3),
          "m2"=matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
```

I want to bind the two matrices (row-bind), and to distinguish the rows, I want to add a column that contains the name of the matrix. I can bind the rows using `r bind`:

```
b <- do.call(rbind, a) %>% as.data.frame
```

which yields

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  3  6  9
4  1  4  7
5  2  5  8
6  3  6  9
```

But how do I add a column containing the names? I can do `b$id <- c("m1","m1","m1","m2","m2","m2")`, but there must be an easier way than this (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it in dplyr / purrr

```
a %>% purrr::map(as.data.frame) %>% dplyr::bind_rows(.id = "origin")
  origin V1 V2 V3
1     m1  1  4  7
2     m1  2  5  8
3     m1  3  6  9
4     m2  1  4  7
5     m2  2  5  8
6     m2  3  6  9
```

That converts the matrices to data-frames before row-binding them.

You can use `bind_rows` on a list of matrices. But it doesn't return what you expect.

```
a %>% bind_rows(.id = "origin")
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  origin    m1    m2
  <chr>  <int> <int>
1 1          1     1
2 1          2     2
3 1          3     3
4 1          4     4
5 1          5     5
6 1          6     6
7 1          7     7
8 1          8     8
9 1          9     9
```

This happens because `m1` and `m2` are vectors (because they are matrices) of the same length, and `bind_rows` sees a list of constant-length vectors as a single data-frame. So the latter call is equivalent to

```
bind_rows(data.frame(m1 = as.vector(m1), m2 = as.vector(m2)), .id = "origin")
```

So, make sure you convert your matrices to data.frames before you bind them together.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
b <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, a)

#     V1 V2 V3
#m1.1  1  4  7
#m1.2  2  5  8
#m1.3  3  6  9
#m2.1  1  4  7
#m2.2  2  5  8
#m2.3  3  6  9
```

or if you not happy with this,

```
b    <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, a)
b$id <- sub("[.].+", "", rownames(b))

#     V1 V2 V3 id
#m1.1  1  4  7 m1
#m1.2  2  5  8 m1
#m1.3  3  6  9 m1
#m2.1  1  4  7 m2
#m2.2  2  5  8 m2
#m2.3  3  6  9 m2
```